# Array of class instances

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

First question here so tell me if anything is not clear.

The program below reads a .txt file, and line by line create a new class instance of a movie, with different parameters such as the title, length, and so on.

I then need to put the different class instances into an array (FilmList) and then do a bunch of operations on this list.

All is going well until the point where I'm checking if the FilmList array was correctly populated. The sub GlobalReport should show me a message for each movie title in the list, however, it seems that all movies are replaced by the last one that was added, as the msgbox in the GlobalReport is showing me only the last movie title.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot

```
Sub main()
    Dim LineList() As String

    LineList = OpenAndImportTxtFile
    Dim FilmList() As film
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(LineList) - 1 'for i = 1 so that the first line is ignored
        Dim NewFilm As New film
        NewFilm.initialiser(LineList(i)) 
        ReDim FilmList(i)
        Set FilmList(i - 1) = NewFilm 'using set first is probably the problem but whithout it I get an error 91
        
    Next i
    Call GlobalReport(FilmList)

End Sub
```

```
Sub GlobalReport(ByVal FilmList)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(FilmList) - 1
        MsgBox FilmList(i).titre
    Next i
End Sub
```

edit: After your comments, the code is like below, but the problem remains

```
    LineList = OpenAndImportTxtFile
    Dim FilmList() As film 'Tried with and without this line but no effect
    ReDim FilmList(UBound(LineList) - 1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(LineList) - 1
        Dim NewFilm As New film
        NewFilm.initialiser (LineList(i))
        Set FilmList(i - 1) = NewFilm
        
    Next i
```

Comment: Move the `ReDim` outside the loop. You can use `ReDim Preserve` inside a loop, but that's expensive and unnecessary.

Comment: Note: you probably want `ReDim Preserve FilmList(i)`.  Without the `Preserve` it loses all of it's previous entry's values.  Or alternatively move it *before* the loop and allocate it all at once with `ReDim FilmList(UBound(LineList) - 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I moved it before, with the syntax you provided, however the problem is still exactly the same... Edit: I also tried with preserve inside the loop but same

Comment: `UBound(LineList) - 1` will miss the last line.

Comment: `Dim NewFilm As film`, `Set NewFilm = New film`.

Comment: Omg BigBen you solved it ! I had no suspicion about this line but here lied the problem ! Thanks a lot !!